# Draw a circle or square around a number in a table cell

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

This is a little challenging to explain.  I'm working on creating displays for golf score cards.  When a score card is displayed, for values that are 1 shot lower than par there should be a circle around the number, for values that are 2 shots lower should have a double circle.  For values that are higher it's the same with squares.  I've solved this issue with background images before for regular stroke play, and it worked ok.  But the new challenge is Match Play, because I have to use cell background color to designate which team won a particular hole, but at the same time I need to show the circles and squares.  I didn't really like the background image solution much from the beginning, because it's not flexible enough to accomodate scores higher than 9, which are rare but do happen, and then the whole display gets throws out of alignment.

I'm not really sure if this is a jQuery question or an HTML5 question or a general HTML question.  Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `border-radius`.

```
<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;" title="Birdie">3</span>

<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 8px; border: 3px double black;
    border-radius: 50%;" title="Eagle">2</span>
```

And for strokes over par:

```
<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;" title="Bogey">5</span>

<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 8px;
    border: 3px double black;" title="Double Bogey">6</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by surrounding the number with a `<div class="birdie"> </div>` and styling the div to have a border with rounded corners, like so:

```
.birdie {
        width: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

Eagle is nearly the same, but change border-style to `double` and border-width to `4px`
This solution should work for all major browsers.  Take out the rounded corners to mark a bogey or double-bogey.

Comment: both tips look promising thanks you!  Didn't even consider trying border-radius before.